# Rails: Viewing associated objects from has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Productline, which has a has_many relationship to Project.

On the apps/views/productlines/show.html.erb page, I would like to iterate over the number of Projects associated to it, like this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
                    <div class="paper-container">
                        <%= link_to(project) do %>
                          <div class="paper-box">
                            <h5><%= project.name %></h5>
                            <div class="img pulsetalk" style="background-image: url();"></div>
                            <hr>
                            <a class="card-btn" href="../status/pulse.html">
                              Project Status
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>  
                <% end %>
```

In my Productline controller, I have this:

```
def show
    @projects = Project.all
  end
```

My question is: What method would allow me to only give back to the view Projects that are associated to the view? Right now all projects are showing up on all Productlines.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean projects of Productline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, and you've got your routes set up following the normal RESTful style (i.e. you're using `resources :productline` in your routes.rb such that the `show` route for a `Productline` would be `/productline/:id`) then you'll want something like this:

```
def show
  product_line = Productline.find(params[:id])
  @projects = product_line.projects
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed,the route of show page should be like this:

`localhost/productline/3 etc.`

```
def show
  @projects = Productline.find(params[:id]).projects
end
```